# How would I throw an exception in this type of scenario in an if else statement

Tags: java, exception

```
  if (upperCaseString.equals("X") || upperCaseString.equals("Y") || upperCaseString.equals("MT")) {
         return upperCaseString;
      } else {
         Integer integerValueOfString = Integer.parseInt(upperCaseString);
         if (integerValueOfString >= 1 || integerValueOfString <= 22) {
            return integerValueOfString.toString();
         } else {

         }
      }
```

I want to throw an exception in the last else block. I tried

```
throw new Exception system.out.println("Not valid range");
```

but that didnt work also I tried a try catch but i do not know what to catch since it is just going into the else

Comment: `throw new Exception("Message");`

Comment: An exception isn't a block of code. I suggest you start off by reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
} else {
    throw new Exception("my Message");
}
```

Also you have to add throws declaration in method signature if you use like in example a checked exception.

You also can throw unchecked exceptions (that are exceptions  `RuntimeException` or extends of it ) in this case it is not necessary to add `throws` in method signature.

Read more about exceptions : [How to throws exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

Comment: ...only if it's a checked exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the wrong way as you are attempting to write
`throw new Exception system.out.println("Not valid range");`,

```
    if (upperCaseString.equals("X") || upperCaseString.equals("Y") || upperCaseString.equals("MT")) 
    {
        upperCaseString = upperCaseString;
    } 
    else 
    {
        Integer integerValueOfString;
        try
        {
            return  Integer.parseInt(upperCaseString);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e1) //Here exception is caught and your custom exception is thrown as per your requirement
        {
            throw new Exception("Not valid range");
        }
        if (integerValueOfString >= 1 || integerValueOfString <= 22) 
        {
            return  integerValueOfString.toString();
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new Exception("Not valid range");
        }
    }
```